# how to Make an Object and use coredata Correctly?

Tags: xcode, core-data, object, iphone-4

I got 5000 district and city pairs. I want to set put those 5000 districts into coredata. Each district has a city and each city can have many districts. I have 2 entities, namely districts and citypair. How do I do so efficiently?

```
for (int i=0; i<[IndonesiaDistrictToSave count]; i++) {

    int index;
    for (int j=0; j<[[IndonesiaDistrictToSave objectAtIndex:i] length]; j++) {
        if([[IndonesiaDistrictToSave objectAtIndex:i] characterAtIndex:j]==','){
            index=j;
        }
    }

    NSString * DistrictName=[[IndonesiaDistrictToSave objectAtIndex:i] substringToIndex:index];
    NSString * CityName=[[IndonesiaDistrictToSave objectAtIndex:i] substringFromIndex:index+1];

    District * theDistrict = (District *)[GrabClass getObjectWithStringOfValue:DistrictName fromTable:@"District" withAttribut:@"Name"];
    theDistrict.City= (City *)[GrabClass getObjectWithStringOfValue:CityName fromTable:@"City" withAttribut:@"Name"];
}
```

getObjectWithStringOfValue is a method to lookup if the object is already exists it will return it, but if the object is not exists, it will be make a new one, and return it

and then I use that code to Save all of Indonesia Districts, there are more than 4500 districts, If I use time interval, I get 0.013773 for each district but it still slow, how can I make it faster?

Is there a way to get a mutablearray proxy of a search result?

Comment: There's a special use of functions that begin with `-get*`. I suggest you use a different prefix.

Comment: Alexsander is right: we run into great trouble, when we used -get* and -add* prefixed methods on ManagedObject subclasses.

Answer (score 1):

Since you seem to think of your entities as sql tables, I rather doubt your fetch is setup efficiently.

Core Data is not SQL. Entities are not tables. Objects are not rows. Attributes are not columns. Relationships are not joins. Core Data is an object graph management system that may or may not persist the object graph and may or may not use SQL far behind the scenes to do so. Trying to think of Core Data in SQL terms will cause you to completely misunderstand Core Data and result in much grief and wasted time.

If you have a batch of potential attribute values to lookup, use the `IN` operator in a predicate to find all matches e.g.

```
NSArray *newName=[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"Tom",@"Dick",@"Harry",nil];
NSPredicate *p=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name NOT IN %@",newName];
```

…then use that predicate for the fetch. Any objects returned already have attribute values in the new data and you can skip creating new objects for them.

Comment: I got 5000 district and city pairs. I want to set put those 5000 districts into coredata. Each district has a city and each city can have many districts. I have 2 entities, namely districts and citypair. How do I do so efficiently?

Comment: I guess the most efficient way would be to populate it once in a sqlite store, copy it back to your Xcode project and include it into the bundle. and on first run on the users device, u copy it to the Documents folder, as you can't alter anything in the bundle.

Comment: Are you populating the store just once in development or is this something that will have to be done often by the user?

Comment: It'll be done the first time the user us my application. I did this in the background though.